# Is it possible to have a remote: true AJAX partial load into a bootstrap modal on desktop, but as a slide-in-from-the-side form on mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails app which is currently working well on desktop, but the UX on a phone is quite bad, especially with bootstrap modals being loaded into the page. Currently to create new objects I load the form into a bootstrap modal using AJAX and pop it into view on the page.

As part of a redesign to make my mobile user experience better I am considering using the responds_to block to design a different layout for my mobile users, and would like the dynamically loaded rails forms (it's all for data entry) to render as a single page and slide in from the right, then slide back out once a user successfully submits the action.

Is this possible? Is there a suitable gem available that might make this easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am considering using the responds_to block to design a different layout for my mobile users

Don't.

You can use the same layout, just set the CSS styling to be different.

---

**Responsive**

You're best using [`media-queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Lots of people get confused / overwhelmed with "responsive" interfaces; the reality is very simple - only use logic to assign classes on a per-platform basis, everything else should be handled by media queries. 99% of it is styling, your logic & flow remains the same.

In your case, I believe `bootstrap`'s modals are responsive (IE they work on phones as well as on desktop) - what you want is to assign different animations depending on the viewport size.

--

*Classes*

The only logic you need are for your classes (how the modal slides in).

We've used the [`browser` gem](https://github.com/fnando/browser) before - it gives you access to some `user_agent` data, including `browser.mobile?`, which means you'll be able to use something [like](https://github.com/fnando/browser#rails-integration):

```
#view
<% styling = browser.mobile? "slide" : "show" %>
<%= link_to "link", "#", class: styling %>
```

I don't have huge experience with bootstrap styling, so I'd have to read up on how to change the modal animation. However, all [CSS3 animations](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) are transitions based on classes; change the class, change the animation.

Comment: Thanks Rich. Is there a reason you think the same layout is the best approach? I've set it up that way for simplicity at the moment, but feel a mobile user ought to see a more mobile-friendly layout than a desktop user (especially displaying tables - large amounts of info seem to look uglier on smaller screens). The modals seem to behave badly on mobile (bootstrap mentions it in their documentation) - specifically their positioning on the screen but also their general usability.

Comment: Thanks Rich, that's certainly given me some thinking to do. I'll mark this as my accepted answer, as I'm sure I'll end up researching and using this suggestion to improve my experience on smaller devices.

Comment: It's really simple with responsive - use CSS for styling and cut out any info you don't need using conditional like the `browser.mobile?` helper; thanks for the upvote btw